# Facebook FQL query error 604 but field is indexable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When I enter a FQL query string into the explorer, or when I simply click on the explorer link provided in the FQL guides example I get the following error message saying that I am using a field that is not indexable:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
      "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
      "code": 604
   }
}
```

Problem is, the fields I am using (the only fields I am using, actually) are called out as indexable and marked with * in the table links. I even tried this with Facebook's example query, with the same problem. This is happening for every FQL query I write and use an indexable field with. I'm not sure where I am going wrong--is something configured wrong?

My example query is the one provided in the Facebook FQL guide:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/

You can link to it in graph api explorer here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1%3Dme%28%29 on

And I am using the following permissions with a user access token (kinda went with a shotgun approach after a while of things not working): export_stream, manage_pages, read_insights, read_stream, user_about_me, user_actions.books, user_actions.music, user_actions.news, user_actions.video, user_activities, user_birthday, user_checkins, user_education_history, user_events, user_friends, user_games_activity, user_groups, user_hometown, user_interests, user_likes, user_location, user_notes, user_online_presence, user_photo_video_tags, user_photos, user_questions, user_relationship_details, user_relationships, user_religion_politics, user_status, user_subscriptions, user_videos, user_website, user_work_history

Answer (score 0):

The query runs fine when trying it from code or from the "FQL Query" tab in the Graph API Explorer tool. It looks like a bug with the Graph Explorer where the query is sent malformed. Will be great if you could file a bug in developers.facebook.com/bugs